# Evento change queda activo cuando elemento desaparece de dom

Tags: javascript, angularjs

en el siguiente codigo al presionar el botón `Configurar hora` se hace visible el input con el [timepicker](https://github.com/jonataswalker/timepicker.js) y se lanza el evento `change`, después se oculta con el botón `Ir a otra pagina`, este botón lo oculta con `ng-if` pero esto provoca que el elemento desaparezca del dom, y el evento lanzado aun sigue a la espera, por lo que al oprimir el botón `Configurar hora` por segunda vez, este ya no funciona, esto en la misma vista lo solucione con `ng-show` para tan solo ocultar el input en el dom, **el problema se da cuando cambio de vista y vuelvo a regresar, ¿Como puedo remover o reactivar el evento de nuevo antes de llamarlo?, ¿o podría re enlazar el componente al evento?**, les dejo una replica del error

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){

    
    $scope.changevalue = () => {
      $scope.configurar = true;
      this.resetTime();
     
    }
    
    $scope.ocultar = () => {
      $scope.configurar = false;
    }
      
    this.resetTime = () => {
      setTimeout(function(){ 
          var timepicker =  new TimePicker('timePicker', {lang: 'en', theme: 'dark'});
  
          timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {
              // este evento solo sucede una vez
              console.log("evt",evt)
              var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
              evt.element.value = value;
          }); // fin on change
      }, 200);// fin timeOut
    }// fin resetTime

})
```

```css
*,:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box;margin:0;padding:0}._jw-tpk-container{position:absolute;width:250px;height:140px;padding:0;background:#fff;font-family:inherit;font-weight:400;overflow:hidden;border-radius:3px;box-sizing:border-box;max-width:250px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;line-height:1rem;font-size:1rem}._jw-tpk-container:after{content:" ";display:block;clear:both}._jw-tpk-container *,._jw-tpk-container :after,._jw-tpk-container :before{box-sizing:border-box}._jw-tpk-container *,._jw-tpk-container .active,._jw-tpk-container :focus,._jw-tpk-container :hover{text-decoration:none;outline:none}._jw-tpk-container._jw-tpk-dragging{opacity:.85!important}._jw-tpk-container._jw-tpk-dragging ._jw-tpk-header{cursor:-webkit-grabbing;cursor:grabbing}._jw-tpk-container ol{text-align:center;list-style-type:none}._jw-tpk-container ol>li{display:inline-block}._jw-tpk-container ol>li>a{display:inline-block;padding:3px 0;width:25px;color:inherit;border-radius:3px;border:1px solid transparent;font-size:1.2rem}._jw-tpk-container ol>li>a:not(._jw-tpk-selected):hover{cursor:pointer;border:1px solid #ccc;border-right:1px solid #aaa;border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;background:#f5f5f5;background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#e6e6e6,#f5f5f5);background:linear-gradient(#e6e6e6,#f5f5f5);box-shadow:0 2px 3px hsla(0,0%,86%,.8)}._jw-tpk-header{position:relative;font-weight:600;text-align:center;cursor:-webkit-grab;cursor:grab;line-height:1.875rem}._jw-tpk-header:after,._jw-tpk-header:before{content:"";display:table}._jw-tpk-header:after{clear:both}._jw-tpk-body{padding:2px 0}._jw-tpk-body:after,._jw-tpk-body:before{content:"";display:table}._jw-tpk-body:after{clear:both}._jw-tpk-hour{width:64.49275%;float:left;margin-right:1.44928%}._jw-tpk-minute{width:34.05797%;float:right;margin-right:0}._jw-tpk-dark{color:#212121;box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #212121}._jw-tpk-dark ._jw-tpk-header,._jw-tpk-dark ol>li>a._jw-tpk-selected{color:#f5f5f5;background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#212121,#545454);background:linear-gradient(#212121,#545454)}._jw-tpk-blue-grey{color:#263238;box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px #263238}._jw-tpk-blue-grey ._jw-tpk-header,._jw-tpk-blue-grey ol>li>a._jw-tpk-selected{color:#cfd8dc;background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#263238,#4f6875);background:linear-gradient(#263238,#4f6875)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/timepicker.js/latest/timepicker.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      <button name="button" ng-click="ocultar()">Ir a otra pagina</button>
      <button name="button" ng-click="changevalue()">Configurar hora</button>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="timePicker" data-ng-if="configurar"  ng-model="hora"     autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer es un error del timepicker, que crear siempre un nuevo elemento. Puedes corregirlo preguntando si el elemento ya existe y luego eliminarlo.

```
this.resetTime = () => {
  setTimeout(function(){
      // Elimina el elemento del timepicker si ya existe
      if(document.querySelector('._jw-tpk-container')) {
          document.querySelector('._jw-tpk-container').remove();
      }
      var timepicker =  new TimePicker('timePicker', {lang: 'en', theme: 'dark'});

      timepicker.on('change', function(evt) {
          // este evento solo sucede una vez
          console.log("evt",evt)
          var value = (evt.hour || '00') + ':' + (evt.minute || '00');
          evt.element.value = value;
      }); // fin on change
  }, 200);// fin timeOut
}// fin resetTime
```